# Golang: print struct as it would appear in source code

Tags: serialization, go, struct, code-generation, pretty-print

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331063/in-go-how-can-i-get-the-string-representation-of-a-struct) but not quite identical.

I'm doing some code-generation, making .go files from within Go. I've got a struct, and I want to generate the text representation of it so that I can insert it as a literal into the generated code.

So, if I had  `myVal := SomeStruct{foo : 1, bar : 2}`, I want to get the string `"SomeStruct{foo : 1, bar : 2}"`.

Is this possible in Go?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the `fmt` package:

> ```
> %#v   a Go-syntax representation of the value
> ```

This is as close as you can come with built-in formatting, after removing the package identifier (`main.` in this example) from the output.

```
type T struct {
    A string
    B []byte
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", &T{A: "hello", B: []byte("world")})

// out
// &main.T{A:"hello", B:[]uint8{0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64}}
```

[Run](https://play.golang.org/p/x6nqCzrFXs)

Comment: I tried this, but when I've got `type Foo string` and `{field : Foo("Bar")}`, it just prints this to `{field : "Bar"}`. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: @jmite: what is the type of `field` in the struct?

Comment: It's type `Foo`

Comment: @jmite: then the type conversion is superfluous, since the string literal can be assigned to the `Foo` type.

Comment: @jmite: this still can't do everything, nested pointers are only going to be printed as `%p` with a type, and values assigned to an interface will only show the underlying type. If you want more detailed output, you need to format it manually.

Comment: Looks like the solution is to implement the `GoString()` method, described in the `fmt` library, thanks!

Comment: Ugh...Correction, this is working for `map` as well, my IDE terminal is stupid and did not print it as a string. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to avoid printing the package name? (in this example print only `&T{A:"hello", B:[]uint8{0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64}}`