# Print list with variable name in it (as it appears in source code file)?

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list:

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]
```

How do I print the list to get this output:

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]
```

The same as what is in my `.py` file?

A similar question appears for Go: [Golang: print struct as it would appear in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979903/golang-print-struct-as-it-would-appear-in-source-code)

But I do not understand it and if Python has anything similar.

For those wanting to know **why**, I need to print these lists to an HTML file. Due to limitations of programming interoperability and not wanting to over-engineer, this is easiest for me to use as code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000934/python-print-a-variables-name-and-value  Maybe this helps?

Comment: Did you try `print(L1)`?

Comment: There is no way, given the list object, to get the `L1 = ` part in the print output, because the list **does not have** that information. Any object in Python can have **any number of names in the source code, including zero**. The Q&A you found for a different programming language doesn't solve that problem in the other programming language, either; and cannot, for a similar reason.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of this? Smells like XY problem, maybe you should use dict, instead of name and value

Comment: Are you okay with hardcoding the L1 name in the code that prints this? It's not clear what your requirements are.

Answer (score 3):

Use an f-string as follows:

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]

print(f'{L1 = }'.replace(', [', ',['))
```

**Output:**

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]
```

Without the call to *replace()* the output will be:

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'], ['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a method I will not encourage you to use, but if you are really sure you want to do this you can do it like this.

I assume that you have a variable which you want to print.

```
L1 = [['Hello', '.', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Joe'],['Hola', '.', 'Mi', 'nombre', 'es', 'Joe']]

# make a copy of the globals
g = globals().copy()

for key, value in g.items():
    if value is L1:
        break

print(f"{key} = {value}")
```

Again, I do not recommend you to use it.